# Is a System.MessageQueue (MSMQ) message lost if my function fails while processing it?

Tags: c#, msmq, message-queue

I send a message using the following code:

```
var transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction())
transaction.Begin(  );

var message = new Message
{
   Body = myContent,
   Recoverable = true
};

m_oMessageQueue.Send( message , myTransaction );

transaction.Commit( );
```

And receive it using a `BeginRecieve` and a `ReceiveCompleted` event handler.

If my event handler fails before calling `EndRecieve`, should the message remain on the queue and be available to a subsequent calls to receive? The behavior I am seeing is that the message is gone forever. (Or maybe there is a timeout after which point it will become available again?)

**Update** The code receiving the message looks like this.

```
var messageQueue = new MessageQueue( myPath );
messageQueue.ReceiveCompleted += messageQueue_ReceiveCompleted_ThrowException;
messageQueue.BeginReceive();
```

For test purposes I throw an exception in the messageQueue_ReceiveCompleted_ThrowException event handler.

I then repeat the above code with a working event handler but i doesn't get called.

Comment: what is your receive queue's EnableConnectionCache set to?

Comment: I didn't set it to anything, what is it for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're using `BeginReceive` with a transactional queue. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329473%28VS.71%29.aspx):

> Note   Do not use the asynchronous
>   call BeginReceive with transactions.
>   If you want to perform a transactional
>   asynchronous operation, call
>   BeginPeek, and put the transaction and
>   the (synchronous) Receive method
>   within the event handler you create
>   for the peek operation. Your event
>   handler might contain functionality as
>   shown in the following C# code.

For failures like this, I believe messages typically go into a dead letter queue or produce a negative acknowledgement, depending on how you configure the `MessageQueue` (which would explain why you aren't seeing them). You can [read more about those options here](http://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/05/26/Tracking-down-where-your-MSMQ-messages-have-gone.aspx).

Comment: Thanks that should help me. Another related question, if I'm using Peek is there a possibility that the message would be picked up by multiple consumers?

Comment: Multiple consumers could `Peek` at the message, but only one would be able to actually `Receive` a particular message. This will probably require a little extra care since two consumers may be in there at the same time - you'll have to decide whether they're looking for that specific message (that `Peek` found), or any old message, and probably be sure to add a timeout to the `Receive` call so the loser doesn't block forever.

Comment: Would BeginPeek and then later ReceiveById using the Id passed in the PeekCompleted, be a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest resolution might be to use BeginPeek or Peek to read the contents of the message without removing it from the queue and once the message is processed, then take the message off the queue.

Answer (score 1):

If the queue is transactional but remote, then you can only receive messages within a transaction with MSMQ 4.0.

[How do I get transactional remote receives with MSMQ?](http://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/12/11/how-do-i-get-transactional-remote-receives.aspx)

Cheers
John Breakwell (MSFT)